# PHP benchmarking: fastest way to parse a $date_string

Tags: php, parsing, datetime, microbenchmark

I have `$date_string = '12/1/2014';`

I need:

1. To parse it into a timestamp number (to save in a DB)
2. And then parse that timestamp to output in a different format, e.g. `December 1, 2014`

I am assuming that using the [DateTime class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) would be the preferred method (and I personally find it very convenient).

```
// timestamp
$date_string = '12/1/2014'; // input
$d1 = new DateTime($date_string);
$date_timestamp = $d1->getTimestamp(); // output

// re-format
$date_timestamp = '1417410000'; // input
$d2 = new DateTime("@$date_timestamp"); // append @ to hint the timestamp
$date_formatted = $d2->format('F j, Y'); // output
```

However, I am curious what would be the *fastest* way to perform both parse operations.

Comment: if the speed of this is an issue, you have far greater problems

Comment: Why are you asking a question and answering it yourself at the same second your post it?

Comment: So is your question, that you don't know how to create your own benchmark?

Comment: Your benchmark is completely unclear. Questions: What is your input data? Which transformation do you want to get? What is correct output data?

Comment: The reason I answered it myself is just to show my results. I was curious to see if anyone else gets similar or different results. But I guess you are right, on this level microoptimization wouldn't matter. Thank you, guys!

Comment: @Geo you are 100% correct with your answer but you need to be more detailed add your benchmark code .. have done a test myself http://codepad.viper-7.com/jHzCxD and `m4` wins which is `date_parse_from_format`

Comment: how can I add my code here? It won't fit in these comments.. :-/

Comment: [Here's the article](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) that encourages answering your own questions, btw

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In a 100,000 loop:

- `date()` = 3.221485 sec
- `date_parse()` = 1.090016 sec
- `date_parse_from_format()` = 0.871224 sec (**the fastest!**)

Comment: Where is your benchmark code ....

Comment: But... this one goes to 11.

Comment: I always get 42 for some reason?